# Feature branch based on master (without checking out master)

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout

I'm trying to find a quicker workflow. When working in large repos, I sometimes find myself waiting 5-8 seconds to just `checkout master`.

Current workflow:

- on feature branch
- `checkout master`
- `checkout -b newBranch`

Is there a way to skip the process of checking out master?

- on feature branch
- `checkout -b newBranch` (**based off of master, not the feature branch**)

Bonus if there is a way to do this & check to see if a `fetch` is needed! (not super concerned about this, just think it'd be cool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including a fetch and using bash's operator to check the exit status:

```
git fetch && git checkout -b newbranch origin/master
```

- `origin/master` is used instead of `master` to branch out from the latest fetched state of the repository (remember that `fetch` doesn't directly update `master`, just `origin/master`)
- use `;` instead of `&&`, if you wanna branch out even if `fetch` failed, for whatever reason.

Comment: Completely off topic, loving your avatar!

Answer (score 2):

`git branch *name-of-branch* *branch-to-branch-from*`

[git branch docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) look for start-point

Comment: so the new flow would be: `git branch newBranch master`, `git checkout newBranch`

Comment: Including fetch: `git fetch && git checkout -b newbranch origin/master`

Comment: @KurzedMetal, I was just about to ask if it was possible to do this incorporating `git checkout -b`. Awesome!

Comment: @KurzedMetal, will you post yours as a separate answer?

Comment: Was justing testing whether it could be done with `-b` @KurzedMetal got there quicker.